# Loop through components in form?

Tags: .net, winforms

I know how to iterate through controls but "components" property does not seem directly available. I can see them when I view the object in runtime but I do not know how to access them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add you code?

Comment: The *components* field (not property) is available by default in any Form class that was created from the project item template.  Look at the form's Designer.cs file.  Note how it is used in the Dispose() method, just use it the same way.

Comment: @Tomzan: which code you expect to see?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it's a private field. Private fields can't be accessed outside of the class so I don't think you'll be able to do it. Unless it is exposed through a property.

Comment: Thanks all, yes, it is a private property I see now. Is it possible to get it through reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use reflection to get what I wanted since .components is private:

```
            Dim formType As Type = myForm.GetType()
            Dim fieldInfo As Reflection.FieldInfo = formType.GetField("components", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            If fieldInfo IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim parent As IContainer = DirectCast(fieldInfo.GetValue(myForm), IContainer)
                If parent IsNot Nothing Then
                    For Each comp As Component In parent.Components

                    Next
                End If
            End If
```